# Dimension error in feeding Keras with Tensorflow dataset

Tags: keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TFRecords file consisting of 60 examples of six Landsat band values for some pixels plus a label for each pixel, and I want to train a Keras classifier with it. But I get a dimension mismatch when I try to load network with the data.

TFRecords file is generated with below structure:

```
# TFRecords file contains below features per each example
bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7','landcover']
columns = [tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32) for k in bands]
featuresDict = dict(zip(bands, columns))
```

And my code for defining generator function and Keras model is as follows:

```
def tfdata_generator_training(fileName, batchSize=None):

  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fileName, compression_type='GZIP')

  def parse_tfrecord(example):
      features = tf.parse_single_example(example, featuresDict)
      # Extract landcover and remove it from dictionary
      labels = features.pop('landcover')    
      labels = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(labels, tf.uint8), 3)
      # Return list of dictionary values (to be convertable to numpy array for Keras) and pixel label in one-hot format
      return list(features.values()), labels    

  # Map the parsing function over the dataset
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_tfrecord)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batchSize)
  return dataset

training_data = tfdata_generator_training(fileName=<my_file_path>, batchSize=1)

def keras_model():
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input

    inputs = Input(shape=(6,1))
    x = Dense(5, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(7, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model = keras_model()
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(training_data.make_one_shot_iterator(), steps_per_epoch=60, epochs=8)
```

But I get below error when running the code:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (6, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3)
```

What is the problem with my code? I also tried to get the dimensions of the input layer and the Tensorflow printout was as follows:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(?, 6, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(?, 1, 3) dtype=float32>)
```

Comment: The data that goes into your model is in the form of vectors of length 6. Therefore, you should specify your input layer:

    `inputs = Input(shape=(6,))`.

It is not required to specify the batch dimension, because the size of the batches you'll feed to the data does not change the model architecture. Can you try this and see if if helps?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and reply, but it still returns an error. This time it says `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, 6, 1)`. Actually 1 was not batch dimension, I meant the input is a 6x1 array.

Comment: Can you try defining your featuresDict as follows:
`columns = [tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32) for k in bands]`?

Comment: Thanks again! That helped me to pass the above mentioned error. But when I want to get the model output on a test data point (a vector of 6 elements such as `x=[0.2251,0.2438,0.253,0.2689,0.2765,0.2026];y= model.predict(x)`, I get this: `Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (6,) but got array with shape (1,)`. How can I do a simple prediction now?

Comment: Your data needs to be arranged in a 'batch' of size 1. You can add a batch dimension by `np.expand_dims(x, 0)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It is fixed now.
Refer to the first part of my question, I still cannot clearly understand why should I get such an error. Could you please tell me why it `expects dense_2 to have shape (6, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3)`?